# Making really simple app including front & backend skills (js, node.js, psql, react...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, rest

I'm trying to make a simple todo app in order to understand how frontend and backend are connected. I read some of the websites showing a tutorial for using and connecting rest API, express server, and database, but still, I was not able to get the fake data from a database. Anyway, I wanted to check if my understanding of how they are connected and talk to each other is correct or not. So could you give some advice please?

First of all, I'm planning to use either Javascript & HTML or React for frontend, Express for server, and Postgres for the database. My plan is a user can add & delete his or her task. I have already created a server in my index.js file and created a database using psql command. Now if I type "" it takes me to the page saying "Hello" (I made this endpoint), and I'm failing to seed my data to the database. Here are my questions↓

1. After I was able to seed my fake data into the database, how should I get the data from the database and send to the frontend? I think in my index.js file, create a new endpoint something like "app.get("/api/todo", (res, req) => ..." and inside of the callback function, I should write something like "select * from [table name]". Also, form the front end, I should probably access certain endpoints using fetch. Is this correct?
2. Also, how can I store data which is sent from the frontend? For example, if I type my new todo to `<input>` field and click the add `<button>`, what is the sequence of events looks like? Adding event listener to button and connect to the server, then create post method in the server and insert data, kind of  (?)  <= sorry this part it's super unclear for me.

   3. Displaying task on the frontend is also unclear for me. If I use an object like {task: clean up my room, finished: false (or 0 ?)} in the front end, it makes sense but, when I start using the database, I'm confused about how to display items that are not completed yet. In order to display each task, I won't use GET method to get the data from the database, right?
   4. Also, do I need to use knex to solve this type of problem? (or better to have knex and why?)
      I think my problem is I kind of know what frontend, server, database for, but not clear how they are connected with each other...

I also drew some diagrams as well, so I hope it helps you to understand my vague questions...

Comment: You're right about /api/todo, and you need to extend that idea. You need to create a set of endpoints (google REST API) that cover all your actions. You Front-End is going to be using this API to display and change the data, so what users do on the front will be mirrored in the database.

Comment: Regarding the database, you'll need one table with todo items. "finished" field will be used as a filter to retrieve only relevant items. I'm not sure you need knex for such a simple app but it's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how should I get the data from the database and send to the frontend?
>   I think in my index.js file, create a new endpoint something like
>   "app.get("/api/todo", (res, req) => ..." and inside of the callback
>   function, I should write something like "select * from [table name]".

Typically you use a controller -> service -> repository pattern:

- The controller is a thin layer, it's basically the callback method you refer to. It just takes parameters from the request, and forwards the request to the service in the form of a method call (i.e. expose some methods on the service and call those methods). It takes the response from the service layer and returns it to the client. If the service layer throws custom exceptions, you also handle them here, and send an appropriate response to the client (error status code, custom message).
- The service takes the request and forwards it to the repository. In this layer, you can perform any custom business logic (by delegating to other isolated services). Also, this layers will take care of throwing custom exceptions, e.g. when an item was not found in the database (throw new NotFoundException)
- The repository layer connects to the database. This is where you put the custom db logic (queries like you mention), eg when using a library like https://node-postgres.com/. You don't put any other logic here, the repo is just a connector to the db.

> Also, form the front end, I should probably access certain endpoints
>   using fetch. Is this correct?

Yes.

> Also, how can I store data which is sent from the frontend? For
>   example, if I type my new todo to field and click the add , what is
>   the sequence of events looks like? Adding event listener to button and
>   connect to the server, then create post method in the server and
>   insert data, kind of (?) <= sorry this part it's super unclear for me.

You have a few options:

- Form submit
- Ajax request, serialize the data in the form manually and send a POST request through ajax. Since you're considering a client library like React, I suggest using this approach.

> Displaying task on the frontend is also unclear for me. If I use an
>   object like {task: clean up my room, finished: false (or 0 ?)} in the
>   front end, it makes sense but, when I start using the database, I'm
>   confused about how to display items that are not completed yet. In
>   order to display each task, I won't use GET method to get the data
>   from the database, right?

If you want to use REST, it typically implies that you're not using backend MVC / server rendering. As you mentioned React, you're opting for keeping client state and syncing with the server over REST. 
What it means is that you keep all state in the frontend (in memory / localstorage) and just sync with the server. Typically what is applied is what is referred to as optimistic rendering; i.e. you just manage state in the frontend as if the server didn't exist; yet when the server fails (you see this in the ajax response), you can show an error in the UI, and rollback state.

Alternatively you can use spinners that wait until the server sync is complete. It makes for less interesting user perceived performance, but is just as valid technical wise.

> Also, do I need to use knex to solve this type of problem? (or better
>   to have knex and why?) I think my problem is I kind of know what
>   frontend, server, database for, but not clear how they are connected
>   with each other...

Doesn't really matter what you use. Personally I would go with the stack:

- Node Express (REST), but could be Koa, Restify...
- React / Redux client side
- For the backend repo layer you can use Knex if you want to, I have used node-postgres which worked well for me.

Additional info: 
I would encourage you to take a look at the following, if you're doubtful how to write the REST endpoints: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgrP6r-cFUQ

Answer (score 0):

> After I was able to seed my fake data into the database, how should I get the data from the database and send to the frontend? I think in my index.js file, create a new endpoint something like "app.get("/api/todo", (res, req) => ..." and inside of the callback function, I should write something like "select * from [table name]". Also, form the front end, I should probably access certain endpoints using fetch. Is this correct?

You are right here, you need to create an endpoint in your server, which will be responsible for getting data from Database. This same endpoint has to be consumed by your Frontend application, in case you are planning to use ReactJS. As soon as your app loads, you need to get the current userID and make a fetch call to the above-created endpoint and fetch the list of todos/any data for that matter pertaining to the concerned user.

> Also, how can I store data which is sent from the frontend? For example, if I type my new todo to field and click the add , what is the sequence of events looks like? Adding event listener to button and connect to the server, then create post method in the server and insert data, kind of (?) <= sorry this part it's super unclear for me.

Okay, so far, you have connected your frontend to your backend, started the application, user is present and you have fetched the list of todos, if any available for that particular user.

Now coming to adding new todo the most minimal flow would look something like this,

- User types the data in a form and submits the form
- There is a form submit handler which will take the form data
- Check for validation for the form data
- Call the POST endpoint with payload as the form data
- This Post endpoint will be responsible for saving the form data to DB
- If an existing todo is being modified, then this should be handled using a PATCH request (Updating the state, if task is completed or not)
- The next and possibly the last thing would be to delete the task, you can have a DELETE endpoint to remove the todo item from the list of todos

> Displaying task on the frontend is also unclear for me. If I use an object like {task: clean up my room, finished: false (or 0 ?)} in the front end, it makes sense but, when I start using the database, I'm confused about how to display items that are not completed yet. In order to display each task, I won't use GET method to get the data from the database, right?

Okay, so as soon as you load the frontend for the first time, you will make a GET call to the server and fetch the list of TODOS. Store this somewhere in the application, probably redux store or just the application local state.

Going by what you have suggested already, 
{task: 'some task name', finished: false, id: '123'}

Now anytime there has to be any kind of interaction with any of the TODO item, either PATCH or DELETE, you would use the id for each TODO and call the respective endpoint.

> Also, do I need to use knex to solve this type of problem? (or better to have knex and why?) I think my problem is I kind of know what frontend, server, database for, but not clear how they are connected with each other...

**In a nutshell or in the most minimal sense, think of Frontend as the presentation layer and backend and DB as the application layer.**

the overall game is of sending some kind of request and receiving some response for those sent requests. Frontend is what enables any end-user to create these so-called requests, the backend (server & database) is where these requests are processed and response is sent back to the presentational layer for the end user to be notified.

These explanations are very minimal to make sure you get the gist of it. Since this question almost revolves around the entire scope of web development. I would suggest you read a few articles about both these layers and how they connect with each other.

You should also spend some time understanding what is RESTful API. That should be a great help.